# website can't login by facebook, no error, just no session

Tags: php, session, web, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I used facebook-php-sdk 4.0 for login.
A few days ago, everything is normal, but suddenly one day log in facebook pop-up a warning box,said submit for login review,some of the permissions blow have not been approved for use by facebook.
I flow the document https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login removed the "user_location" permission.then the warning box disappeared,but can not login anymore.
The same code on the other website work normally.
So I think if anything happend on mangatown.com just like blocked or something like that?
code like that:

```
<?php
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;

session_start();

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($_facebook['app_id'], $_facebook['secret_key']);

if (is_loggedin()) {
    location($_system['web_url']);
}

$redirect = function ($url) {
    header('Location:'.$url);exit;
};

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($_system['web_url'].'connect/facebook.php');
try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
    $msg = "Facebook Error, code: ".$e->getCode()." with message: ".$e->getMessage();
    error_log($msg);
    return header('Location:'.$_system['web_url']);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $msg = "Facebook Error, code: ".$e->getCode()." with message: ".$e->getMessage();
    error_log($msg);
    return header('Location:'.$_system['web_url']);
}
if(!$session) {
    $redirect($_system['web_url']);//$session always null..
}
try {
    $me = (new FacebookRequest(
        $session, 'GET', '/me'
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
} catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
    $msg = "Facebook Error, code: ".$e->getCode()." with message: ".$e->getMessage();
    error_log($msg);
    return header('Location:'.$_system['web_url']);
}
$fb_user_id = $me->getId();
$fbEmail = $me->getEmail();
```

$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();is always null.
what's wrong?

Comment: same behavior for any browser ?